# ios picker multi dimensional array

Tags: arraylist, picker

```
pickerData =    [[["A"], ["i","ii","iii"]],[["B"],["iv","v","vi","vii"]]]
}
```

> > Error: Contextual type 'String' cannot be used with array literal
> >     Please advice how to use the array

Answer (score 0):

Heterogenous literal collection types must be annoated:

Try this:

```
let pickerData: [[[String]]] =
[
    [
        ["A"],
        ["i","ii","iii"]
    ],
    [
        ["B"],
        ["iv","v","vi","vii"]
    ]
```

]

Comment: **already used above override func **                                                             'var pickerData: [[String]] = [[String]]()'        **if i use your recommendation i am getting** 'Initialization of immutable value 'pickerData' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it'

Comment: That means it's compiling.  That error will go away when you actually reference pickerData

Comment: But UIPicker is invisible/hidden to select if I remove your code its visible furing run

Comment: This is a separate issue.  I'd recommend opening a new question and state your new issue.  In the meantime if you could mark this answer as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: my picker has two sections and each item if selected in the first picker has its own subdivisions to select from the second picker.